# ClaimsAuthorizationManager not on System.Security.Claims

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2015, claims-based-identity

I'm trying to add claim auth on my mvc project but I can't implement the ClaimsAuthorizationManager. I saw in a lot of tutorials on the web that you need to create a custom authorization manager but my VS don't seem to find the ClaimsAuthorizationManager.

[image: Visual Studio 2015]

My Intellisense can't find the reference.

[image: Intellisense]

My project is being built on .Net Framework 4.5 and the System.Security is in my references on the project.

Can anyone help?
Thanks.

Comment: [`ClaimsAuthorizationManager`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsauthorizationmanager(v=vs.110).aspx): "**Assembly:**  System.IdentityModel (in System.IdentityModel.dll)"

Comment: Thank you so much! After adding this reference the System.Security.Claims gained that method.